# List where Clause

Tags: c#, linq, list

The code below work succesfully to find if a value exists in a list. How do I add a where clause such that only for list items where Type = "File"

```
if (MyGlobals.ListOfItemsToControl.Any(x => x.sItemName == info.FullName)) // Dont allow duplicates
{
}
```

**Pseudo Code for what i want**

```
if (MyGlobals.ListOfItemsToControl.Any(x => x.sItemName == info.FullName).Where(y => y.Type == "File")) // Dont allow duplicates
{
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your filter (`Where`) should be before `Any`

```
if (MyGlobals.ListOfItemsToControl
                  .Where(y => y.Type == "File")
                  .Any(x => x.sItemName == info.FullName))
```

You can also combine both conditions in `Any` like:

```
if (MyGlobals.ListOfItemsToControl
                  .Any(x => x.Type == "File"
                  && x => x.sItemName == info.FullName))
```

Answer (score 1):

instated of where you can simply use

```
if (MyGlobals.ListOfItemsToControl.Any(x => x.sItemName == info.FullName && x.Type == "File")) // Dont allow duplicates
{
}
```